# MVC 3 - Nested layouts - sections don't render in Areas

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

### Problem:

Given this nested layout structure:

```
~/Views/Shared/_layoutBase.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/_layout.cshtml
```

Where `_layoutBase.cshtml` is the layout for `_layout.cshtml`.

Any sections defined in the layout files render their content fine in pages under `~/Views/...`

However, for views in an area, the sections are never rendered.

### Setup:

`_layoutBase`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        @RenderSection("footerScripts", false)
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

`_layout.cshtml`:

```
@section footerScripts{
    @RenderSection("footerScripts", false)
}
```

"content" view:

```
@section footerScripts{
$(function () {
    SetFocusOnForm("CaptchaCode", "NextButton");
});
}
```

The content of section `footerScripts` never gets rendered in a view in an area.  It does get rendered in a view that is under the `~/Views` folder.

Area `_ViewStart.cshtml`:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

### Question:

Can you see anything wrong?!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I am unable to reproduce the problem. Here's my setup and steps I did.

1. Create a new ASP.NET MVC 3 application using the Internet Application Template
2. Add `~/Views/Shared/_LayoutBase.cshtml`:

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <body>
   @RenderBody()
   <script type="text/javascript">
       @RenderSection("footerScripts", false)
   </script>
   </body>
   </html>
   ```
3. Replace the contents of `~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml` with this:

   ```
   @{
       Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutBase.cshtml";
   }

   @section footerScripts{
       @RenderSection("footerScripts", false)
   }

   @RenderBody()
   ```
4. Right click on the project and add an Admin area
5. Add a TestController to this admin area and add a corresponding `~/Areas/Admin/Views/Test/Index.cshtml` view:

   ```
   @{
       ViewBag.Title = "Index";
       Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
   }

   <h2>Index</h2>

   @section footerScripts{
       alert('ok');
   }
   ```
6. Run the application and navigate to `/admin/test/index`
7. The alert is shown

Comment: +1:  I believe you.  I will go through it all tomorrow, too pie eyed now.  There has to be an error in my code, but blowed if I can see it.  Many thanks.

Comment: Just what I was looking for. Nested Render within Layouts... Thx!

Comment: In addition to this, if you like to add an area of e.g "admin"
you can just add this to the _ViewStart.cshtml of the area

@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_AdminLayout.cshtml";
}

Add an _AdminLayout.cshtml from the root Shared folder that looks like this.

@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutBase.cshtml";
}

@section footerScripts{
    @RenderSection("footerScripts", false)
}

@RenderBody()

Answer (score 7):

### The Reason Why:

I have got up this morning and saw the problem straight away:

I had the @section blocks in a Partial View.  In MVC 3, that WON'T work!!

ARGH!

I really appreciate Darin's effort, that effectively provided proof that sections do work in Areas as expected.  But the real cause was this.

I forgot they were in a Partial View, because I have a mvc 3 wizard that uses partial views for steps.  It works so well and consistently, using ajax if javascript is available, that you forget what you are doing.

Please give Darin a vote, but this is the real answer.

Comment: If this solved your problem you should accept your own answer.